# How long should you wait before drilling into a new stucco wall?

Tags: exterior, stucco, downspout

The last coast went on our new stucco wall 4 days ago. I understand stucco should cure for 14 to 30 days before you paint it. But what about drilling holes? We would like to re-attach the gutter. How long should we wait before drilling holes in it to attach the gutter downspout?

Comment: Drilling into the stucco or though the stucco to the studs/wood?  New stucco will probably not hold screws well.

Comment: I wouldn't have a house w/o a gutter any longer than I had to, even if you said no.

Comment: Got in touch with contractor who did the work - he said it was good to go for screws. Says its like concrete at this point - I guess the full cure is for painting? Its not a lot of weight for these screws